# "I have to" in past tense

Tags: past-tense

I want to figure out how to properly say "I have to (e.g., leave)" in past tense.

"I had have to leave", is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. 
This is a special use of the verb "have", but it is still the ordinary verb "have", which forms other tenses in the normal way:

> I have to leave.
>
> I had to leave.
>
> I have had to stop. (I couldn't think of a plausible scenario for this form with "leave")
>
> I had had to leave.
>
> I will have to leave.
>
> I will have had to leave. (!)
>
> I'm going to have to leave.
>
> I would have to leave.
>   Like other uses of "have", it does not normally take continuous forms: there is no "I am having to" except for a few special uses.

Comment: Come now, Colin, I find that I'm having to disagree with you. Cheers.

Comment: Drunk to pub landlord: *You're my last chance for a nightcap! Please don't throw me out, or I will have had to leave every pub in town!*

Comment: @FF Colin is obviously less of a reprobate.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it must be thus.

I had to leave.

The past tense of have is had. So the correct answer is I had to go.

Answer (score 0):

In the past tense, it's

```
I had to leave.
```

In the present perfect tense, it's

```
I have had to leave.
```

In the future tense, it's

```
I will have to leave.
```

In the past perfect tense, it's

```
I had had to leave.
```

In the conditional tense, it's

```
I would have to leave
```

if we're talking about conditional present; and

```
I would have had to leave
```

if we're talking about conditional perfect.

The form `have to` is used as a replacement for `must` in all tenses except for the present tense, where you have either `I must leave` or `I have to leave`.

So the only thing you have to to to use `have to` in all the tenses in which it can be used is basically to conjugate the verb `to have` in the appropriate tense.

Answer (score 0):

Either `I had to leave` or `I have had to leave`.

Anyway, at the time when I first studied English (>30 years ago) there was also `I ought to leave`, with a slight change of meaning. As far as I know it would sound more like expressing an obligation to do (past of `must`) rather than a duty or necessity (past of `have to`).